# Get TEXT value of a CLOB OID in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have a database table that looks like:

```
create table answers(
   id int not null,
   question_id int not null,
   answer text null
)
```

This table was originally build by Hibernate using the @Lob attribute for the "answer" column.  I did not realize it at the time, but when setup that way, Hibernate stores an OID in the column instead of the actual text.  Everything works fine when I use Hibernate to retrieve the values since it automatically converts the OID to the CLOB string, however it is becoming a performance problem and I'd like to get rid of the OID.

```
select * from answers
ID     QUESTION_ID     ANSWER
===============================
1       123             55123
2       234             51614
3       345             56127
should be
ID     QUESTION_ID     ANSWER
===============================
1       123             Male
2       234             203-555-1212
3       345             555 Main St. New York, NY
```

My desire is to add an extra column to the table "ANSWER_VALUE TEXT" and do something like below to get the actual value into the table, then change Hibernate around to not use the @Lob designator

```
update answers set ANSWER_VALUE= getValueFromOID(ANSWER)
```

Does that "getValueFromOID" function exist?  If not, could I get some pointers on how to create one or at least how to fetch the actual value of an OID?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Thanks goes to [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name).  Solution is:

```
update answers set answer_value = lo_get(cast(value as bigint))
```

Note - the `lo_get` function appears to be present in Postgres 9.4 or higher.  For earlier versions, I don't see a way of doing this directly.  I'm currently running 9.0, but this just accelerated my upgrade plans.

Comment: Did you try `loread()`? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/lo-funcs.html

Comment: loread does not appear to be available to me as either postgres, or the database owner.  "No function matches the given name and argument types"

Comment: Perhaps it's because the correct function name is `lo_read`.

Comment: Documentation for lo_get is here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/lo-funcs.html

Comment: I've used a little tweeked version: `update answers set answer_value = convert_from(lo_get(cast(value as bigint)), 'UTF8')`

Answer (score -1):

Query : `SELECT encode(lo_get([OID], [offset], [length]), 'escape');`

You can get the actual data present at particular OID and then execute update query.
e.g.,

```
temp_table => SELECT encode(lo_get(238026, 0, 10), 'escape');
 encode 
--------
 world
(1 row)
```